# How do you fix image duplication in Slick2d?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

There is a glitch with slick2d. The pictures I make it draw on the window duplicates. I am on a windows 7 computer running eclipse. I am using paint.net for my graphics this is what it looks like:

I would have an image of it but I can't yet, sorry.

This is my image code:

```
    /**
 * Images
 */

// Title

Image title;
public static int titleX = 100;
public static int titleY = 500;

// Play Button

Image play;
public static int playX = 210;
public static int playY = 500;

// Options Button

Image options;
public static int optionsX = 310;
public static int optionsY = 500;

// Quit Button

Image quit;
public static int quitX = 410;
public static int quitY = 500;

    public void init(GameContainer Gc, StateBasedGame Sbg)
        throws SlickException {

    /**
     * Images
     */

    title = new Image("gfx/main_menu/title/new_title.png");
    play = new Image("gfx/main_menu/buttons/play_button.png");
    options = new Image("gfx/main_menu/buttons/options_button.png");
    quit = new Image("gfx/main_menu/buttons/quit_button.png");
}

    public void render(GameContainer Gc, StateBasedGame Sbg, Graphics G)
        throws SlickException {

    /**
     * Background
     */

    G.setColor(Color.white);
    G.fillRect(0, 0, w*s, h*s);

    /**
     * Images
     */

    title.draw(titleY*s,titleX*s);
    title.draw(playY*s,playX*s);
    title.draw(optionsY*s,optionsX*s);
    title.draw(quitY*s,quitX*s);
}
```

Comment: Never mind I fixed it! It was a pretty funny mistake though i will leave it up!

Comment: If you're going to leave the question up please answer it yourself.

Comment: Why are all your position variables static? There's no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are drawing the Image "title" four times, while never calling draw on the other images (play, options and quit).